# RAID 5 status = "Initialize"

Tags: 14.04, raid, storage, plex, raid5

I recently built a PC and loaded 14.04 on it. My motherboard (ASRock z97 Extreme 4) has the capability to run a RAID array built into it (pardon my terminology if I'm wrong, I'm not really that good at this stuff). I have a 250GB SSD in slot 0 and five 3TB hard drives in slots 1-5 that I plan to use to store media for a Plex Server.

When the PC is booting, I have the option to go into the RAID configuration utility. I create a RAID 5 Volume and set the 5 hard drives to be disks to be used. After this point, it shows that a RAID volume exists, with the status set to "Initialize". It never changes past that point. When viewing the disks after booting up, the 5 hard drives show up individually, but the RAID Volume does not show up.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Edit: all of my hard drives are showing up as being a RAID member. I guess my real question now is how to "Initialize" the volume and then mount it?

Answer (score 0):

The "initialize" message you are seeing is most likely because the RAID 5 array is building right now. It takes up to 24 hours (or longer if your array is in use) to initialize/rebuild your array.

I have a 7 disk (2TB) Raid 6 that takes nearly 30 hours to rebuild when I swap out a drive. Mind you, it is in use during that time so it takes longer. Your disks are 3TB, and because they are bigger it will take longer.

A reason that Ubuntu is not seeing the RAID could be because you need to install 'dmraid' first, which enables the system to see the RAID array correctly.

See if running this command will help:

> sudo apt-get install dmraid

Also, unless you are trying to setup a dual boot with Windows, I would recommend using 'mdraid' over 'dmraid'. But that is another subject.